# Yandex MapKit 3.0 Crash

Tags: android, yandex-maps, yandex-mapkit

Yandex MapKit crashes on `MapKitFactory.initialize(this)` line

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    MapKitFactory.setApiKey(YANDEX_MAP_KEY)
    MapKitFactory.initialize(this)
    setContentView(R.layout.advert_activity)
}
```

Stacktrace is

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:
>   "/data/data/com.appname.app/app_lib/libgnustl_shared.so" is 32-bit
>   instead of 64-bit
>       at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:928)
>       at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1621)
>       at com.yandex.runtime.internal.ReLinker.loadLibrary(ReLinker.java:82)
>       at com.yandex.runtime.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:122)
>       at com.yandex.runtime.Runtime.init(Runtime.java:99)
>       at com.yandex.mapkit.MapKitFactory.initialize(MapKitFactory.java:18)
>       at com.appname.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:41)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1601)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this issue https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/issues/4/.
MapKit 3.0 doesn't have armv8.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried everything, but only that solution worked:

Add this line to project's `build.gradle`

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", 'armeabi', 'arm64-v8a'
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude '/lib/mips64/**'
            exclude '/lib/arm64-v8a/**'
            exclude '/lib/x86_64/**'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: down-voted, because it should be `armeabi` (the `.so` location & `abiFilters`) only, in order to load 32 bit libraries on both architectures. filtering and then excluding is a little pointless. just alike answering the own question immediately after having posted it, appears to be fabricated content.